# Php post json data

Tags: php, post

I have a simple form with 2 fields and I want to read the data from it and use it with `$_POST`.

This is the output when I debug the `$_POST` function:

```
file_put_contents( 'debug' . time() . '.log', var_export( $_POST, true));
```

OUTPUT:

```
array (
    'form' => 
            array (
                'id' => '36e3113',
                'name' => 'New Form',
            ),
    'fields' => 
                array (
                    0 => 
                        array (
                            'id' => '0',
                            'type' => 'text',
                            'title' => 'Your name',
                            'value' => 'John',
                            'raw_value' => 'John',
                            'required' => '1',
                        ),
                    1 => 
                        array (
                            'id' => '1',
                            'type' => 'tel',
                            'title' => 'Phone number',
                            'value' => '12345',
                            'raw_value' => '12345',
                            'required' => '1',
                        ),
                ),
)
```

I want to use `$POST` to only assign values of `Your name` to `$name` and `Phone number` to `$number` variable.

Comment: $name = $_POST["form"]["name"]

Comment: You should really read the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: `$fields = array_column($_POST["fields"], "value", "title");`

Answer (score 2):

You can get it like.

```
$name = $_POST['fields'][0]['value'];
$number = $_POST['fields'][1]['value'];
```